# Iphone Printing, Specify a Specific Printer

Tags: iphone, printing

Is there a way to specify which printer to use for an air print job bypassing the user selection dialog box?

Comment: How would you know which printer, why would you want to limit the user's options, and no I don't believe you have private access to the Airprint APIs

Comment: Specify a "specific" printer vs ... specifying a non-specific printer? :)

Comment: Really? Ok, Just to be clear for all of the comedians out there.  When you print on IOS, normally a box comes up to allow the user to choose a printer.  Is there a way to specify a printer in the code so the dialog does not come up to allow the user to choose a printer.  "Pre-Choose" a printer I guess is yet another way to ask the question.  I guess yet another way to ask a question is if there are any non-private APIs to do this?  There are reason's for my madness here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presently there is no way to do this without Jail braking, etc.